# Android TimePicker not giving the desired result

Tags: java, android, timepicker

Hello I'm trying to calculate user's sleeping hours of 7.5.the app should suggest that the user should be at bed at an exact time. For example, she chooses 7:00 Am as her waking time, the app will suggest that by 11:30 Am she should be going to bed What I tried so far is this:

```
public class TimepickerActivity extends Activity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

Button btn1, btn2;
TimePicker picker;
TextView tv;

private int hour;
private int minute;

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;

@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_timepicker );

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnShow);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnSleepingTime);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
    picker = (TimePicker) findViewById (R.id.timePicker1);

    setCurrentTimeOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();

}


 // display current time
public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {


    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // set current time into textview
    tv.setText( new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                                    .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

    // set current time into timepicker
    picker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    picker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, 
                                     timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);

    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
         new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
            int selectedMinute) {
        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.HOUR, - selectedHour);
        c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, - selectedMinute);

        // set current time into timepicker
        picker.setCurrentHour(hour + 7);
        picker.setCurrentMinute(minute + 30);

        // set current time into textview
        //tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
        //      .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

        tv.setText( picker.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":" + picker.getCurrentMinute().toString()  );



    }
};

private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
       return String.valueOf(c);
    else
       return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}


public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

When I input 7:00 am as my waking time, the result is giving me 2:30 pm. But it should be 12:30 pm. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: What is `Calendar c` in `onTimeSet()` for? You never use it for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's correct. If you input 7:00am + 7.5 hours = 14:30 = 2:30 am. The program is working correctly.

**EDIT**: you almost did it:

```
public class TimepickerActivity extends Activity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private static final int SUB_HOUR = -7;
    private static final int SUB_MINUTE = -30;

    [...]

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
        int selectedMinute) {

    // Gets current time
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Assign hour set in the picker
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, selectedHour)
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

    // Have Calendar calculate the substraction of hours and minutes
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR, SUB_HOUR);
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, SUB_MINUTE);

    // Get the hour and the minute calculated
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    [...]
```

Of course this means this previous assignment:

```
    hour = selectedHour;
    minute = selectedMinute;
```

is now useless and you can remove it.

By the way, you didn't take into account the day, e.g. choosing 1:30 am would return 6:00 pm but for the day before.

**EDIT**: I corrected my code.

Comment: Yes it is working like that, but my application is asking the user of her waking time, and the app should suggest that the user should be at bed at an exact time. For example, she chooses 7:00 Am as her waking time, the app will suggest that by 12:30 Am she should be going to bed.

Comment: Well this is not clear in your question. I suggest you add this more detailed example in your question. Also 12:30 + 7:30 = 8:00 am and not 7:00 am, so the correct result would be 11:30pm not 12:30am.

Comment: @dymmeh: that won't work. He will be setting negative hours like he's doing it right now.

Comment: @m0skit0 - I was thinking the calendar was smart enough to do this on its own. I believe "roll" instead of "add" automatically corrects the date if you go negative.. Ex -1 hours = 11 pm

Comment: @dymmeh: look again at his code. He's not using `Calendar` for anything.

Comment: @m0skit0 - ah I see now. He never actually gets the value out of it.

Comment: By the way, you didn't take into account the day, e.g. choosing 1:30 am would return 6:00 pm but for the day before. - what do u mean by this?

Comment: Choosing 1:30 am in the picker if we're at 15/10/2012 will return 6:00 pm but this time is for 14/10/2012.

Comment: private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
             new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
   
   public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
     int selectedMinute) {
    
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, selectedHour);
       c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
       c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, SUB_HOUR);
       c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, SUB_MINUTE);
       hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
       minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
       
tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":").append(pad(minute)));
 }};

Comment: "Yes" would have been enough :) What's the input?

Comment: my input is 7:00 am but the output is 6:23 :( i followed thru ur code

Comment: Hello @m0skit0 when I tried to run once again the app, I noticed that it's not changing the AM/PM?

Comment: Sure, this is closely related to what I said before: "you didn't take into account the day", same as you're not taking into account the AM/PM part. `onTimeSet()` does not send this information (same goes with the day).

Comment: Can you give me some links of tutorials so I can work on this? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you working with 24h format, it's easier and more standard than AM/PM. Then you can convert back to AM/PM. The days are already calculated automatically by the `Calendar`.

Comment: so should I use this? timePicker1.setIs24HourView( true ); ??

Comment: Please do not ask everything. Try by yourself and if you have problems, you can make a new question :)

Comment: Okay m0skit0, I will post another question.. ^^